# Solving trig functions with graphing calculator

Tags: trigonometry

I know that $ \sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1$, but I am not sure how to verify this with a graphing calculator. I am using a TI-Inspire CAS.

I also want to find $ \sin^2(\theta) - \cos^2(\theta)$ and am not sure how. Can someone kindly assist, thanks?

Comment: Well you could compare your outputs to your last question with $-\cos 2\theta$ to see if your solution is correct.

Comment: logic suggests that my last question is -1, but is there a way to plug those equations in and solve and get 1 or -1 in a graphing calculator?

Comment: How do you mean? The last equation you had is equal to the expression I gave in my comment? $\sin^2\theta -\cos^2\theta$ does not in general equal either $\pm 1$

Comment: What would count as verification on your calculator? You can choose any $\theta\in \Bbb{R}$ you want, and always calculate $ \sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta)$ to get an answer of $1$.

Comment: I see what you are all saying and think I have it now. If someone wants to post (Chinny84 or graydad), I will give you both credit. Thanks.